# Find node with href of <a> tag like "?"

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/Home.aspx">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/About.aspx">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/About/History.aspx">History</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/About/Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/About/Email.aspx">Email</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/About/Contact/Phone.aspx">Phone</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/FAQ.aspx">FAQ</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to select nodes based on part of the a tag href using an XPATH expression.

I don't have the full href, only the last part.

So say I want to find the node that links to "History.aspx" I would use something like:

```
//@href()[. = 'History.aspx']
```

Comment: Your example--"I have the following HTML:"--did not get posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `//a[contains(@href, 'History.aspx')]` to get the entire anchor node.  if you want just the `href` path, then `//a[contains(@href, 'History.aspx')]/@href`.

Hope that helps.